# We should make it obvious what meta.stackexchange is for

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

When I go to a subreddit on Reddit, I see immediately in the sidebar what its scope is. When I go to *stackexchange.com* and click "*Feedback always welcome*", I get this place where I can ask **questions**.

Bug reports and feature proposals are not questions, and users should get reinforced that they are in the right place here.

The purpose of meta.stackexchange *is* explained on the help pages, but they are hard to reach: there is a miniature [help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help) button on the bottom of each page. Clicking *help* in the top bar shows *Tour* (which seems useless), *Help Center* (which discourages me further), and *What's Meta?*, a link to an essay about the purpose of meta.

Guys (m/f), it can be really easy to show purpose in simple language. For inspiration, check out [/r/announcements](https://reddit.com/r/announcements), [/r/blog](https://reddit.com/r/blog), [/r/netsec](https://reddit.com/r/netsec), [/r/oney](https://reddit.com/r/oney), [/r/rust](https://reddit.com/r/rust), [/r/trees](https://reddit.com/r/trees).

What do you think?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

New visitors to Meta are already shown a banner and a sidebar entry explaining what Meta is for.

[image]

Comment: Yep, I guess I clicked away that message long ago and revisited Stack Exchange a couple of years later.

Comment: @bgeron I have to admit, I had to browse incognito to make sure this stuff was still displayed. I don't often log out of SE.